# How to prepare the JSON payload from the response in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I am getting response from one API and need to prepare the payload from that response.
For example the response as like

```
    {
      "data": {
        "total_count": 5,
        "userIds": [1,2,3,4,5]
   }
```

Need to make the payload from the response to other API like

```
{
"users": [
      {
        "user_id": 1,
        "invite_amount": 100,
      },
      {
        "user_id": 2,
        "invite_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "user_id": 3,
        "invite_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "user_id": 4,
        "invite_amount": 100
      },
      {
        "user_id": 5,
        "invite_amount": 100
      }
    ]
}
```

Above payload need to send to the another API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def userIds = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).data.userIds

   def payload = [:]

   def users = []
   userIds.each { userId ->
       def user = [:]
       user.put('user_id', userId)
       user.put('invite_amount', 100)
       users.add(user)
   }
   payload.put('users', users)

   vars.put('payload', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
   ```
3. That's it, you will be able to refer the generated payload value as `${payload}` where required

More information:

- [JsonSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) and [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/03/09/how-to-extract-data-from-json-response-using-jmeter/#example-json-paths) link

Basically you need to use JMeter `JSON Extractor`

[image]